# HTTP Put via php client

Tags: php, client

I'm writing a small 'app' for a accounting site called Xena.biz

The system has an API that uses oAuth2 to connect to. All that I have sorted out - I can perfectly retrieve the information I need. Now I need to submit a PUT string back to Xena - here is where I can't figure it out.

The system is build on a file called XenaClient.php which contains all the authorization calls and all the requests.

Here is an example on how I retrieve information :

```
<?
require('XenaClient.php');
const CLIENT_ID     = 'SECRET';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'VERY SECRET'; 
$xenaclient = new XenaOAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
$xenaclient->setAccessToken($_COOKIE["MaskedCookieName"]);

$ordertask = $xenaclient->fetch('https://my.xena.biz/Api/Fiscal/'.$_GET["fiscal"].'/OrderTask/'.$_GET["orderId"]);
var_dump($ordertask);
?>
```

But now I want to SEND information via PUT. According to the XenaClient.php script, I should use the command $xenaclient->fetch($url,$parameters);

So this is my shot

```
require('XenaClient.php');
const CLIENT_ID     = 'SECRET';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'VERY SECRET'; 
$xenaclient = new XenaOAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
$xenaclient->setAccessToken($_COOKIE["MaskedCookieName"]);


$xenaclient->fetch('https://my.xena.biz/Api/Fiscal/96946/Order/243936250/Confirmation',array('ConfirmationDate'=>NULL,'ConfirmationReportLayoutId'=>261205291));
?>
```

This doesn't turn anything back, or doesn't create the wanted effect inside the accounting system. No help to get from Xena themselves, so this is why I ask you guys, hope you can help me.

Heres a few pointers:

The API resource: https://dev.xena.biz

XenaClient.php: https://github.com/EG-BRS/Xena.ExampleApp.PHP/blob/master/XenaClient.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XenoOAuth2Client::fetch](https://github.com/EG-BRS/Xena.ExampleApp.PHP/blob/cb856fe1df677e42aaf98be75df4f5f3d2c58562/XenaClient.php#L219) tells you, that the *third* parameter to the fetch function - although optional - determines the method of the request. Default ist GET (`XenaOAuth2Client::HTTP_METHOD_GET`), so if you want PUT, you should explicitly provide the appropriate PUT parameter (other methods see [the XenoOAuth2Client class constants](https://github.com/EG-BRS/Xena.ExampleApp.PHP/blob/cb856fe1df677e42aaf98be75df4f5f3d2c58562/XenaClient.php#L56):

```
$xenaclient->fetch(
    'https://my.xena.biz/Api/Fiscal/96946/Order/243936250/Confirmation',
    array('ConfirmationReportLayoutId'=>261205291),
    XenaOAuth2Client::HTTP_METHOD_PUT
);
```

most APIs consume json today, *perhaps* it's supposed to be json...

```
$xenaclient->fetch(
    'https://my.xena.biz/Api/Fiscal/96946/Order/243936250/Confirmation',
    json_encode(array('ConfirmationReportLayoutId'=>261205291)),
    XenaOAuth2Client::HTTP_METHOD_PUT
);
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but this didn't solve my issue. Could I have been sending my array in a wrong way ? All data is set up on Json/xml on the server. Am I sending my information the right way ?

Comment: @Xelot I assume you actually get an access token like in https://github.com/EG-BRS/Xena.ExampleApp.PHP/blob/master/index.php

Comment: also according to the api https://dev.xena.biz/api/#!/Order324532ApiOrder/ApiOrder_PutConfirmation the ConfirmationDate is optional, so you leave it out or make it an integer (unix timestamp).

Comment: I know, I tried to put the current unix timestamp on the request - still nothing happens.

Comment: @Xelot I'm pondering right now, if the $parameters should be a json-encoded string ... that would mean ... well ... I write it into my answer

Comment: @Xelot also, you should look at the return value of that function (var_dump perhaps) or post the error messages, if there are any

Comment: YOU, are truly a life saver Jakumi :) - the third parameter was the missing link. I have been trying all day to json_encode that array, but now it works !! MANY THANKS